# Merge multiple lines in same file based on column 1

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

I'm still learning programming and I've tried many things but just cannot get the correct format. I have a **tab delimited** file with 17 columns and many (around 50.000) rows. The file is already sorted by first column. I want to merge rows that have the same first column (A), but all other 16 columns are different and I want to keep all the information in one row, preferably in the same column with **semicolon ;** as a delimiter between them. I want to keep tab as a delimiter in the output file. Thank you so much for the answers and if you could also explain the answer where I went wrong that would be even better :).

I've tried so far:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NF>1{a[$1] = a[$1]";"$2}END{for(i in a){print i""a[i]}}' filename.txt

perl -F',' -anle 'next if /^$/;$h{$F[0]} = $h{$F[0]}.", ".$F[1];
END{print $_,$h{$_},"\n" for sort keys %h}' filename.txt
```

FILE FORMAT (other 15 columns have the same format as column B)

```
A     B     C    
123   fvv   ggg
123   kjf   ggg
123   ccd   att
567   abc   gst
567   abc   hgt
879   ttt   tyt
```

The output I want (I need all 17 columns and for columns 2-16 I need the same output as in column B and C). All cases of B should be under B and all cases of C should be under C and all cases of D should be under D etc. So the output has 17 columns just like the input and instead of 50.000 rows, it now should have around 20.000, because there are many repeats for column 1 (for this particular file):

```
A     B                C
123   fvv;kjf;ccd      ggg;ggg;att
567   abc;abc          gst;hgt
879   ttt              lll
```

Comment: `sed ':1;$!N;s/^\(\(\S\+\s\+\).*\)\n\2/\1;/;t1;P;D' filename.txt`

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what I want. It gives output in such a way that it repeats all 16 columns in this way (but for 16): 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 

and since i have for some cases 50 rows, with the same 1st row, this makes it hard to read as well as give an error due to so many columns (16 x 50 = 800 !!) .

Comment: Hang on, what output do you want for the multiple columns? Should all different cases of "B" be under "B"? Or should they be concatenated? Please [edit] your question and add a more representative example of your input and desired output so we can see how you want us to deal with the multiple columns.

Comment: Yes all cases of B should be under B and all cases of C should be under C and all cases of D should be under D etc. So the output has 17 columns just like the input and instead of 50.000 rows, it now should have around 20.000 (for this particular file).

Comment: If you don't mind having the values separated by commas instead of semicolons you could try with `gnu datamash` e.g. assuming `infile` is sorted by 1st column you could run `{ head -n 1; datamash -g 1 $(printf 'collapse %s ' {2..15}); } <infile | column -t`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{
      if(NR!=1){a[$1]=$2";"a[$1]}
      else print $0}
    END{
      n = asorti(a, b);
      for (n in b) {
      print b[n],a[b[n]]
      }
    }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl can do this handily, using a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %stuff;
my @header = split ' ', <>;

#read in the data to "stuff"
while ( <> ) { 
   my ( $key, $value ) = split; 
   push ( @{$stuff{$key}}, $value ); 
}

print join ("\t", @header ),"\n"; 
foreach my $key ( sort keys %stuff ) {
   print $key, "\t", join ";", @{$stuff{$key}},"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
A   B
123 fvv;kjf;ccd;
567 abc;abc;
879 ttt;
```

Where you went wrong? Honestly, I would suggest it's in trying to compress it all into a one liner. That is - in my opinion - really bad practice. At best, it promotes inscrutable code that's hard to follow.

The above could be condensed down, but it *really* pays to do it longhand first.

In order to support multiple columns, then you start to hit a slight bit of a nuisance with column widths.

This works, but produces output that indentation isn't neatly aligned:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %stuff; 

my ( $id, @header ) = split ' ', <>;

while ( <> ) { 
   my ( $key, @values ) = split; 
   my %row;
   @row{@header} = @values; 
   push ( @{$stuff{$key}{$_}}, $row{$_} ) for keys %row;
}

print join ( "\t", $id, @header),"\n";
foreach my $key ( sort keys %stuff ) {
   print join ("\t", $key, map { join ";", @{$stuff{$key}{$_}}} @header), "\n";
}
```

Output of:

```
A   B   C
123 fvv;kjf;ccd ggg;ggg;att
567 abc;abc gst;hgt
879 ttt tyt
```

If tab separation isn't suitable for your needs, you can use `sprintf` to do the formatting:

```
my $format = '%12s';
print map { sprintf($format, $_) } ( $id, @header),"\n";
foreach my $key ( sort keys %stuff ) {   
   print map { sprintf($format, $_) } ( $key, map { join ";", @{$stuff{$key}{$_}}} @header),"\n";
}
```

We make some use of `map` here, which I appreciate isn't exactly an obvious thing.

What it does is take a list, and apply a transformation to each element. So - in the above example:

```
print join ("\y", map { join ";", @$_ } ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]) )
```

Will generate:

```
1;2;3   4;5;6   7;8;9
```

The `map` operation is saying 'join each subarray on ;' and then return that as a list... that we can then join with a tab. That's basically what the above is doing.

Comment: I rolled back my edit (which, ironically enough, added a one-liner and was written before your warning against them) because I noticed that your solution only works for 2 fields. The OP has multiple fields and has only included 2 as an example.

Comment: Good point - I'll amend my example. (And might try and one-liner-it, but might not :))

Comment: This script gives me only column 1 and 2 and for columns 3-17 only column name, rest is empty.

Comment: Yes, sorry, still rejigging it with the new sample input.

Comment: Amended. Works with sample data now.

Comment: With your sample data as above, or with your actual data set?

Comment: With my actual data. But my data is only bigger not different. Somehow I still get an output file despite the error, but now one case of D is under C and the other under F and so on. Basically everything is messed up. I'm grateful for your help and everyone else’s but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Do you have any empty columns? Because that changes the problem.

Comment: No, no empty columns.

Comment: OK. So - first question. Does the solution above work for you, if you reuse the sample data you've given? If so, then it means the code works, but there's something different with the data set. We need to identify which lines are breaking at that point.

Comment: No it doesn't work even with sample data. The newest solution gives an empty file.

Comment: OK. Sorry, I don't know why then, because it definitely works on my system. The 'output' segment is a copy/paste of what gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

A perl solution:

```
$ perl -F"\t" -anle 'if($.==1){print; next} push @{$k{$F[0]}},@F[1..$#F]; 
  END{print "$_\t" . join(";",@{$k{$_}}) for sort keys(%k)}' file 
A   B   
123 fvv;kjf;ccd
567 abc;abc
879 ttt
```

This can work on an arbitrary number of fields. It does, however, require loading quite a few things into memory and that might be a problem if your file is large.

---

As for where you went wrong, we can't tell you unless you explain what actually happened but, off the top of my head, you perl attempt would fail because:

- You are using `-F,` which sets the field separator to a comma when your input has tabs.
- You are using `-l` and `print "foo\n"`. The `-l` already adds a newline to each print call, so you'll have multiple, blank lines.
- You are using `$h{$F[0]}.", ".$F[1];` to append, so the first time that is run and `$h{$F[0]}` is not defined, you will add an extra `,` at the beginning of your stored value.
- You are only looking at the second field, ignoring all others.

Similarly, your `awk` will fail because:

- You are printing `foo""bar` which will concatenate the output with no space between each field. You want `print foo,bar` and you also want `OFS="\t"` for tab-separated output.
- You are only looking at the second field, ignoring all others.

Answer (score 0):

apologies for this one-liner, but here it goes --

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} {for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) { if (!a[$1]) a[$1]=$1FS$i ;else a[$1]=a[$1]";"$i};if ($1 != old) b[j++] = a[old];old=$1 } END{for (i=0; i<j; i++) print b[i] }' 1

123 fvv ;kjf;ccd
567 abc;abc
879 ttt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    function p(n,A){
        s = n
        for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
            s = s "\t" A[i]
            A[i] = $i
        }
        if(n)
            print s
    }
    NR==1{
        print
        next
    }
    $1==n{
        for(i=2;i<=NR;i++)
            A[i] = A[i] ";" $i
        next
    }
    {
        p(n,A)
        n = $1
    }
    END{
        p(n,A)
    }
    ' file
```

Answer (score 0):

*I want to merge rows that have the same first column (A), but all other 16 columns are different and I want to keep all the information in one row*

You got some fine answers, but I want to point out to you that what you've described in those 30 words is known in SQL as a **join**.  If you import your 50,000 lines into two tables in SQLite, you get the effect you want with

```
select * from R join S on r1 = s1
```

where *r1* and *s1* are column names that you determine.

There are a lot of advantages to using SQL for something like this, especially as the join and selection criteria grow more complex.  It's one of the reasons SQL was invented.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you misunderstood the problem. In SQL parlance, the problem most resembles a GROUP BY where the aggregating functions concatenate strings.

Comment: Not a misunderstanding, just a simplification.  The JOIN is the hard part (and it is a join).  The concatenation is easy.   It could be done in the caller, or in SQL with `SELECT r1, r2 || ';' || s2, r3 || ';' s3`, etc.